# Inactive view in SecondViewController after the transition to it with custom animation through the navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, custom-transition

I have 2 view controllers (ViewController and SecondViewController) and 1 navigation controller:[image]

My project using custom transition animation from ViewController to SecondViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.8
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        let container = transitionContext.containerView
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from) else { return }
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else { return }

        transform.m34 = -0.0019
        container.layer.sublayerTransform = transform
        container.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)
        fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        fromView.layer.position    = CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)) {
            fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-.pi/2, 0, 1.0, 0)
        }
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
}
```

In ViewController (where door image) I use а delay to start the transition animation and go to the SecondViewController (where green background).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let transitionManager = TransitionManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        })
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let navigationViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else { return }

        navigationViewController.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
    }
}
```

SecondViewController has Button press function:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(view.isUserInteractionEnabled)
    }

    @IBAction func tapBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("btn pressed") //it is not worked. Why?
    }
}
```

Animation works correctly, but SecondViewController (green background) does not respond to button presses. Code in SecondViewController

```
print(view.isUserInteractionEnabled)
```

return true. Where is the problem in my code? I want to press the button to work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a glitch in the editor 
Try:
- Restarting Xcode
- Cleaning the Project
- Deleting the Button and it's reference and then re-adding them

Comment: is button.isEnabled set to true (either in code or in the settings to the right)?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled in code (btn.isEnabled = true) and in Main.storyboard settings

Comment: Try deleting DispacheQueue.main.asyncAfter() and running self.performSegue directly.

Comment: or use something like "perform(#selector(yourseguefunction), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)" (yourseguefunction is the function thats segues)

Comment: I am delete DispacheQueue.main.asyncAfter() but self.performSegue is not working in viewDidLoad! I do not know why... I am add a button to ViewController and put self.performSegue code in button action. Animation is work correctly, but Button action in SecondViewController still not working...

Comment: And I am try use "perform(#selector(yourseguefunction), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)" but Button action in SecondViewController still not working

Comment: I am add solution of this question

Answer (score 0):

**Solution.** Remove this in TransitionManager:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)) {
   fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-.pi/2, 0, 1.0, 0)
}
```

And add this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:  transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-.pi/2, 0, 1.0, 0)
}) { (finished) in
    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
}
```